# Как полностью удалить Django через termux?

Tags: android, django, termux

Как полностью удалить Django через termux?

Comment: Так же, как и устанавливали, только наоборот

Comment: `pkg uninstall django` пробовали?

Comment: Александр, да, однако папка с django так и осталась

Answer (score 1):

Удалить Django:
pip uninstall Django

Answer (score 1):

```bash
pip uninstall django
apt autoremove --purge django
```